# How to add name value pair to existing query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to add new name ,value pair to existing query string when the user click on some button.

i'm using jquery for client side operations.

any idea..?

thank in advance!

Comment: Use Andy E.'s solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/2880929#2880929

Comment: Can you give more details ? What is your `query string` ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Yes. some details on `query string` please.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('#yourId').click(function(){
   var href = window.location.href;
var indexOfCanc = href.indexOf('#');
if(indexOfCanc === -1){
  if(href.indexOf('?') === -1){
     href+="?newparamter=my";
  }else{
     href+="&newparamter=my";
  }
 }else{
  var newHref = href.substring(0, indexOfCanc);
  var locationHash = href.substring(indexOfCanc); 
  if(href.indexOf('?') === -1){
     newHref += "?newparamter=my"+locationHash;
  }else{
     newHref += "&newparamter=my"+locationHash;
  }
 }   


   //use the new href for example reload the page with the new parameter:
   window.location.href = href;
});
```

Comment: This will work only if you are 100% sure you already have an existing query item in the parameter.

Comment: This works only if url does not contain anchor **#elementid** (fragment part): _myserver/path?QueryStringParameters#elementid_, for an example. Please update.

Comment: added the handling of the hash

Comment: I did it this way so that you could make a function that parses a string and doesn't relay on window.location.hash

Answer (score 0):

Using regExp:

```
var href = window.location.href,
    toAdd,
    pattern1 = /\?/gi,
    pattern2 = /#/gi;
if (href.match(pattern1) != null) { toAdd = "&" }
else { toAdd = "?" }
toAdd += "param=val";
if (href.match(pattern2) != null) {
    var arr = href.split('#');
    href = arr[0] + toAdd + '#' + arr[1];
}
else { href += toAdd; }
```